# How to add a button that enables the user to insert a link in a textarea located in the front-end?

Tags: html, forms

I'm using the following plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/question-and-answer-forum/

It as a textarea which enables the user to post a question. The author told me [how to allow html](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-question-and-answer-forum-any-possibility-of-adding-the-following-features?replies=3) on it.

But I was wondering how to add a buttons which enables the user to use html, say, attaching a link to a word (like you do here at StackExchange sites).

I think the same should apply to commenting forms.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a JavaScript editor just like the one used in a new/edit post/page editor
only here the editor is:

[WMD-Editor](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/) (i think)

and WordPress uses an editor named: [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

In both cases it's a matter of attaching the editor to a textarea. you can use [Dean's FCKEditor For WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fckeditor-for-wordpress-plugin/) which uses the powerful WYSIWYG [CKeditor](http://www.CKeditor.com)
and integrates it into the comments textarea.

**Update**
i just saw this http://c.hadcoleman.com/wordpress-plugins/wmd-editor-wordpress-plugin/ which is just what you need.